# I don't know why one variable array gets updated in the loop

Tags: arrays, types, fortran

Look at the code below,

```
program hw1

implicit none

real, parameter :: G =1.4
integer :: i, j 
real :: Mii
real, dimension(3) :: cf
real, dimension(96,3):: L_D
real, dimension(96) :: Mi
real :: test
cf=(/0.003,0.004,0.005/)
Mii=0.5
i=0

do while (Mii .le. 10.1)
    Mi(i)=Mii
    i=i+1
    Mii=Mii+0.1
end do 

10 format(f2.1, 5x, f2.5)
open (unit =1,file="L_D_1.txt")
do i=0,2
    do j=0,size(Mi)-1
    print *, Mi(j)
    L_D(j,i)=((1-Mi(j)**2))!/(G*Mi(j)**2)+(G+1)/(2*G)*log((G+1)*Mi(j)**2/(2+(G-1)*Mi(j)**2)))/(4*cf(i))
    end do
end do
end program hw1
```

if you look at the line containing L_D, it is basically just updating L_D array after calculating its value from Mi array value. The problem is that Mi array gets updated somehow after the first ith loop even though I don't have any line that updates the Mi array itself. For example, I should get Mi=0.5 when j =0 and Mi=0.6 when j =1 and so on. But after the first ith loop(i=0) when i becomes 1, Mi array gets updated and Mi(0) (corresponding to j=0) becomes 0.75 somehow.

I can code this in some other language but idk why it doesn't work for fortran.

Comment: Are you aware that Fortran arrays are '1' indexed meaning that the first array element is Mi(1) not Mi(0)? By starting i and j at 0, you are accessing your arrays out of bounds which is probably giving you your unexpected results. You can declare your arrays to start at zero like this: real, dimension(0:96) :: Mi or you can join the real programers (Fortran programmers) and have your loop go from 1 to size(Mi) and forget all those something -1 all those 'other' languages make you do.

Comment: `10.2 - 0.5` yields `9.7`, where `10.2` is the terminating condition which is no longer less or equal than `10.1`. This means you are trying to store 97 values on an array of 96 members. If you print `i` after the first loop, you will see it will print `97`. From 0 to 97, that's 98 iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Two things I notice when I look at your code:

**Fortran Arrays start at index 1 by default**

If you have a declaration like

```
real, dimension(96,3):: L_D
```

then `L_D` has indices between (1,1) and (96,3), as opposed to most other languages, where the indices would run from (0,0) to (95,2). In your loops, you let your indices run that range.

I recommend compiling with run-time checks to see where you go wrong, e.g.:

```
$ gfortran -o hw1 -fcheck=all hw1.f90
$ ./hw1 
At line 17 of file hw1.f90
Fortran runtime error: Index '0' of dimension 1 of array 'mi' below 
lower bound of 1
```

You can fix that by either correcting the limits of the loop, or by specifically setting the range of indices in the declaration:

```
real, dimension(0:95, 0:2) :: L_D
```

**Adding 0.1 to an aggregator every loop inflates rounding errors**

There is a good reason that loops with floating point iterators are no longer allowed in Fortran. It's better to use conversions:

```
do i = 0, 95    ! Assuming range Mi(0:95)
    Mi(i) = (i/10.0) + 0.5 
    ! Note: don't use (i/10), that would result in an integer.
end do
```

or even with implicit loops:

```
Mi = [ ((i/10.0)+0.5, i=0, 95) ]
```

This also ensures that you're not accidentally overrunning the index range, as you do up there: There are 97 values in `(0.5, 0.6, 0.7, .. 10.1)` but your array only has 96 elements.